# Frames per second and junk collection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In simple Unity projects, I can easily reach 1000fps in builds. However, I tend to have GC issues in these types of projects. My question is that does FPS affect the GC poorly. My logic behind it was that => script runs and allocates memory -> scripts are executed once per frame -> therefore if the fps is high, should it accumulate garbage more quickly and into to very big chunks?

For eg. let's say we have a simple script that creates a list, fills it with data and then destroys the list, every single frame.

Comment: Method `Update()` is called once by frame, you should use `FixedUpdate()`

Comment: Why do you need to recreate this list every time? Can't you just keep it in memory? What is stored in your list?

Comment: The problem itself is a made up one, what matters is that we're dealing with scripts that allocate memory and deallocate memory often. Let's say that unity collects garbage every 10 seconds. Therefore, the faster the game runs, the bigger the garbage payload will be in when it comes to collecting it. Would this then mean, that limiting the game fps would actually make the game run smoother (as GC spikes tend to be awful for performance).

Comment: It depends on what you are doing with the memory and when. I don't think that Unity itself will allocate more memory if you have more fps. If you want to reduce the GC spike have a look at their new [Incremental Garbage Collection](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/11/26/feature-preview-incremental-garbage-collection/)

Comment: For more informations about the Unity's Automatic Memory Management have a look on the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingAutomaticMemoryManagement.html)

Answer (score 1):

Time spent on garbage collection is largely a function of how frequently garbage reaches amounts that is necessary to garbage collect, which could be expressed as a product of how much garbage is produced on the average frame and how many frames are run per second.

So yes, if you really can not reduce how much garbage you are creating per frame, you could reduce the amount of time spent on garbage collection by running fewer frames per second.

This is why it is [advised to design your application to reduce the amount of garbage that is created](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/fixing-performance-problems#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b595):

> ### Reducing the amount of garbage created
>
> Let’s examine a few techniques that will help us to reduce the amount
>   of garbage generated by our code.
>
> #### Caching
>
> If our code repeatedly calls functions that lead to heap allocations
>   and then discards the results, this creates unnecessary garbage.
>   Instead, we should store references to these objects and reuse them.
>   This technique is known as caching. In the following example, the code
>   causes a heap allocation each time it is called. This is because a new
>   array is created.
>
> ```
> void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
> {
>     Renderer[] allRenderers = FindObjectsOfType<Renderer>();
>     ExampleFunction(allRenderers);
> }
> ```
>
> The following code causes only one heap allocation, as the array is
>   created and populated once and then cached. The cached array can be
>   reused again and again without generating more garbage.
>
> ```
> private Renderer[] allRenderers;
>
> void Start()
> {
>     allRenderers = FindObjectsOfType<Renderer>();
> }
>
>
> void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
> {
>     ExampleFunction(allRenderers);
> }
> ```
>
> #### Don’t allocate in functions that are called frequently
>
> If we have to allocate heap memory in a MonoBehaviour, the worst place
>   we can do it is in functions that run frequently. Update() and
>   LateUpdate(), for example, are called once per frame, so if our code
>   is generating garbage here it will quickly add up. We should consider
>   caching references to objects in Start() or Awake() where possible, or
>   ensuring that code that causes allocations only runs when it needs to.
>   Let’s look at a very simple example of moving code so that it only
>   runs when things change. In the following code, a function that causes
>   an allocation is called every time Update() is called, creating
>   garbage frequently:
>
> ```
> void Update()
> {
>     ExampleGarbageGeneratingFunction(transform.position.x);
> }
> ```
>
> With a simple change, we now ensure that the allocating function is
>   called only when the value of transform.position.x has changed. We are
>   now only making heap allocations when necessary rather than in every
>   single frame.
>
> ```
> private float previousTransformPositionX;
>
> void Update()
> {
>     float transformPositionX = transform.position.x;
>     if (transformPositionX != previousTransformPositionX)
>     {
>         ExampleGarbageGeneratingFunction(transformPositionX);
>         previousTransformPositionX = transformPositionX;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Another technique for reducing garbage generated in Update() is to use
>   a timer. This is suitable for when we have code that generates garbage
>   that must run regularly, but not necessarily every frame. In the
>   following example code, the function that generates garbage runs once
>   per frame:
>
> ```
> void Update()
>
> {
>
>     ExampleGarbageGeneratingFunction();
>
> }
> ```
>
> In the following code, we use a timer to ensure that the function that
>   generates garbage runs once per second.
>
> ```
> private float timeSinceLastCalled;
>
> private float delay = 1f;
>
> void Update()
> {
>     timeSinceLastCalled += Time.deltaTime;
>     if (timeSinceLastCalled > delay)
>     {
>         ExampleGarbageGeneratingFunction();
>         timeSinceLastCalled = 0f;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Small changes like this, when made to code that runs frequently, can
>   greatly reduce the amount of garbage generated.
>
> #### Clearing collections
>
> Creating new collections causes allocations on the heap. If we find
>   that we’re creating new collections more than once in our code, we
>   should cache the reference to the collection and use Clear() to empty
>   its contents instead of calling new repeatedly.
>
> In the following example, a new heap allocation occurs every time new
>   is used.
>
> ```
> void Update()
> {
>     List myList = new List();
>     PopulateList(myList);
> }
> ```
>
> In the following example, an allocation occurs only when the
>   collection is created or when the collection must be resized behind
>   the scenes. This greatly reduces the amount of garbage generated.
>
> ```
> private List myList = new List();
> void Update()
> {
>     myList.Clear();
>     PopulateList(myList);
> }
> ```
>
> #### Object pooling
>
> Even if we reduce allocations within our scripts, we may still have
>   garbage collection problems if we create and destroy a lot of objects
>   at runtime. Object pooling is a technique that can reduce allocations
>   and deallocations by reusing objects rather than repeatedly creating
>   and destroying them. Object pooling is used widely in games and is
>   most suitable for situations where we frequently spawn and destroy
>   similar objects; for example, when shooting bullets from a gun.